# LocalStorage update date in browser tabs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a server time, which when clicked on + increases, with a click on the minus decreases. If you first increase / decrease the time, and then open the page in a new tab, the starting time will be displayed, not the reduced / enlarged one. Why? I kind of used the localStorsge correctly. What's my mistake?

index.php

```
<div id="timer"></div>
<button id="plus">+</button>
<button id="minus">-</button>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
var counter = 0;

$('#plus').on('click', function (event) {
    counter++;
    localStorage.setItem('counter', counter);
    update();
});

$('#minus').on('click', function (event) {
    counter--;
    localStorage.setItem('counter', counter);
    update();
});

function update() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'datetime.php',
        timeout: 1000,
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'counter=' + counter,
        success: function (response) {
            // $("#timer").html(response);
            // localStorage.setItem('response', response);

            if (localStorage.getItem('response') !== null) { 
                $('#timer').html(localStorage.getItem('response'));
            }       
            window.setTimeout(update, 1000);  
        }
    });
}       

update();
```

});

datetime.php

```
<?php 
$counter = $_POST['counter'] ?? 0;
echo date('d/m/Y h:i:s', time() + (int)$counter * 3600);

?>
```

Comment: I'm curious, why do you call `update` again in your success callback? Wouldn't that kinda throw it into an infinite loop of updating?

Comment: Why do you expect the value set at a previous tab to be set at next page? Where does the code check `localStorage` value? `counter` is set to `0` when each `.html` `document` is opened.

Comment: I call call update in a loop, in order for the time to be real at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing any kind of setting the `#timer` from the stored value, for example, add before the initial `update()` call:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('response') !== null) { 
    $('#timer').html(localStorage.getItem('response'));
}
```

This will set the element's content to the stored value (if any value is stored for the provided key - by specification, `localStorage.getItem(key)` returns `null` if the key is not set).

Comment: Sorry, I saw a small bug. Open two tabs with this page. Then I increases time in first tab, in the second tab, the value changed. Then I increases time in second tab, in the first tab, the value changed. But now when I want to increase the value. When you click on + nothing happens. Why is that? Where is the mistake? The code updated. Thank you!

Comment: You probably expect localStorage behaves differently from what it really does - in the previous version, you weren't getting the "response" key, now you aren't neither getting the "counter" key nor setting the "response" key anywhere - I'm not sure what your intention is, but if you expect a value to be shared between instances (browser tabs) through the localStorage, either set a key in an action AND get it where it's meant to be used.

Comment: Further, it would probably be better if you separated setter part (the ajax call & localStorage setters) from the update to an action function, so the update loop would only check the storage and change the #timer.